# Is there a way of checking what type of authentication a website is using?

Tags: python, urllib2, exchangewebservices, suds

I'm trying to use python with suds to connect to a microsoft exchange server, but I can't authenticate and download the services.wsdl file.

I have also tried just using urllib2 to try and connect, but that also fails.
I can however authenticate and download the Outlook Web Access page.

I've tried using ntlm auth, but that also gives me a 401 error. Is there are way of checking what type of authenication I need, so I can check if I was using the type of auth in the first place.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in [RFC 2617, "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication"](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), the `WWW-Authenticate` response header tells you which method of authentication you should use in your request.

Comment: Thanks, using firefoxes live HTTP headers I found out the the Outlook web access page accepted both NTLM authentication and Basic authentication, while the services.wsdl page requires NTLM auth.

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://www.getpostman.com/apps to know the type of authentication. Hit the url once from this, then from the errors you will get to know the type of authentication.

Comment: How he postman application knows the authentication type. Is that telling based on the errors? I have to use the authentication type in postman that's why am looking for answers, but not automatically knows authentication type